# C++ first item in list disappearing

Tags: c++, list

In this program, the right side of the "list" is the only part that is directly accessible.  However, when displaying the list, the left side needs to be printed on the screen as well.  The only way to get the left sides data is to transfer it over to the right side by moving the fence.  Here's what I have so far:

```
void display(textList& s)
//! ensures: s = #s and displays the contents of s
{
textList sTemp;

int leftL = s.leftLength();

s.moveToStart();

cout << "<";
for (int i = 0, lastItem = (leftL - 1); i < leftL; i++) {
    cout << s.rightFront();

    if (i < lastItem)
        cout << ",";

    s.advance();
}   //end for
cout << ">";


cout << "<";
for(int i = 0, z = s.rightLength(), lastItem = (z - 1); i < z; i++) {
    Text x;

    s.removeRightFront(x);
    cout << x;
    sTemp.addRightFront(x);
    if (i < lastItem) {
        cout << ",";
    } // end if
}   // end for
cout << ">" << endl;

s.transferFrom(sTemp);

}   // display
```

So basically I move the fence so I have access to all the data, then print the first value, then advance the fence one value over until the length of the left side has been reached, I then print out the right side.

My problem is that the very first value of the right side always goes missing.  What's the problem?  I've spent a long time trouble shooting, but I can't seem to find it; I'm fairly certain it's somewhere in the code for printing the right side.

Comment: What is a fence and left list and right list in the context of a list?

Comment: I don't think we can solve this without a complete example; better still a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: textList is the list type.  It initially has the value of <><> until something is added.  Data can only be added to the right side, so it would look like this: <><"a", "b", "c" etc...>.
When the fence is moved [s.advance()] it would look like this: <"a"><"b", "c">.  After a second time: <"a", "b"><"c"> etc....

s.moveToStart() "resets" the list so everything is in the right side: <><"a", "b", "c">

What other information is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Changed my approach.  Instead of manipulating "s", I just created a copy that I could mess around with without any repercussions down the line.  I then advanced the fence on the copy and printed out the right side by the same approach as the left.

In summary.
Made copy.
Stored left length -- z.
moved everything to right side.
for loop (z times).
   printed the data.
   advanced fence.
stored right length -- z.
for loop (z times).
   printed data.
   advanced fence.

```
void display(textList& s)
//! ensures: s = #s and displays the contents of s
{
textList newS;
newS = s;
int  z = newS.leftLength();
newS.moveToStart();

cout << "<";
for (int i = 0, lastItem = (z - 1); i < z; i++) {
    cout << newS.rightFront();

    if (i < lastItem)
        cout << ",";

    newS.advance();
}   //end for
cout << "> ";

cout << "<";
for (int i = 0, z = newS.rightLength(), lastItem = (z - 1); i < z; i++) {

    cout << newS.rightFront();
    newS.advance();

    if (i < lastItem) {
        cout << ",";
    } // end if
}   // end for
cout << ">" << endl;


}   // display
```